# How can I send erc20 tokens at once from MULTIPLE wallets to a single address?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, erc-20, wallet-transfer, batch

I have a specific question.

Is there any tool or wallet to manage multiple wallets and batch transfer tokens?

Im not too familiar with contracts, so would prefer something easy to use with a UI
https://heliowallet.com/send-from-multiple-addresses

I'd like to be able to batch transfer tokens from a wallet that allows this, preferably with an option to edit the gwei and gas fee

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the regular ERC20 or ERC721 tokens, then the only option is for the wallets to give allowance for some contract to withdraw the tokens. That requires a transaction from each of the wallets.

Once the allowances are in place, the contract can get the tokens from each of the wallet in a single transaction. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a wallet/utility which supports such functionality, since the use case is not very common. The problem is that you anyway need to have the allowances in place, so you could just anyway directly transfer the tokens to wherever needed.